# Switch function fires when not called, also default not prevented while using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, addeventlistener

I want a button that display different texts in an area depending if clicked or doubleclicked, or no text at all if not clicked, also right click shouldn't show any menu.

```
<button id='test'>click me</button>
<p id='description'></p>
```

```
const descriptrion = document.getElementById('description');

function trySwitch(val){
  let answer=""
  switch(val) {
    case 1: answer="text number one"
    break;
    case 2: answer="text number two"
    break;
    default: answer= "literally nothing"
  }
  return description.innerHTML= answer;
}
const test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('click', trySwitch(1));
test.addEventListener('dblclick', trySwitch(2));
test.addEventListener('auxclick', function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

the area shows "text number one" regardless the button is dblclicked or not clicked at all. Right click on button shows default browser menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are immediately invoking the function `trySwitch` this will pass the value returned by the function(i.e `answer`) to `addEventListener` rather than passing a function.

- Wrap the invoking expression of function in another function.
- And also you don't need to `return` `description.innerHTML = answer;`

```js
const descriptrion = document.getElementById('description');

function trySwitch(val){
  let answer=""
  switch(val) {
    case 1: answer="text number one"
    break;
    case 2: answer="text number two"
    break;
    default: answer= "literally nothing"
  }
  description.innerHTML= answer;
}
const test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('click', () => trySwitch(1));
test.addEventListener('dblclick', () => trySwitch(2));
test.addEventListener('auxclick', function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<div id='description'></div>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling it twice, here:

```
test.addEventListener('click', trySwitch(1));
test.addEventListener('dblclick', trySwitch(2));
```

`trySwitch(1)` and `trySwitch(2)` aren't functions, they are function *calls*. What you pass to `addEventListener` are results of evaluation of `trySwitch(/* 1 or 2 */)`, so some strings, hence on click/dblclick nothing's going to happen.

Make `trySwitch` a higher order function:

```
function trySwitch(val) {
  return function() {
    let answer=""

    switch(val) {
      case 1: answer="text number one";
        break;
      case 2: answer="text number two";
        break;
      default: answer = "literally nothing";
    }

    return description.innerHTML= answer;
  }
}
```